# Pyqt5 Python3 QPushButton default StrongFocus color or tab selected color

Tags: python-3.x, colors, pyqt5, stylesheet, qpushbutton

I am trying to figure out a way to change the color of a QPushButton in PyQt5 using Python3.

I can set the background color and the hover color, but the programs keeps the focus color or the

strongfocus color as a default one. Cannot find anything about it, I load my qss file StyleSheet in my

main.py.

like

```
QPushButton{
    background-color: #9de650;       #works fine
}


QPushButton:hover{
    background-color: green;         #works fine
}

QPushButton:focus {
    background-color: red;           #doesnt work if the focus color is the color of the button you can
    }                                # change using tab to navigate among a list of buttons

QPushButton:strong:focus {           #doenst work
    background-color: red; 
    }

QPushButton:pressed {                #doesnt work get the tab color
    background-color: green; 
    }
```

I cant understand why QPushButton:pressed doesnt work. I am at the beginning and no connect or clicked functions on the buttons on my script. I am using Designer, and the color I get on my QPushButton is the same one I get in the designer preview.

THe same behaviour if I save the qss code directly into ui file in designer.

While tabbing between my list of button I can see them assuming the red color for a very short time

before turning blue, red is my focus choosen color.

any hint ?

Comment: I tested your stylesheet and (after removing the comments, which should be done using `/* comment */` in css) it works. I don't understand what you're referring to with "strong focus", also, there's no `:strong` pseudo state for Qt.

Comment: I just found about strongfocus somewhere where they were talking about using enter or spacebar to press a button highlighted by moving with tabspace. In my case the buttons behave correct as long as I hover on them but the one that can be moved with tabspace doesnt get the focus color

Comment: I believe you're confusing the focus behavior (which depends on the [focus policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum)) and the appearance: the reason of the focus (whether it's set from tab navigation, mouse clicks/wheel or even without any specific reason) doesn't influence it. Anyway, as said, I can't reproduce your issue: using the css you provided, I can correctly see the buttons becoming red as long as they have focus (using the tab key or *after* clicking them). What system are you on, and what PyQt version? Are you sure you're not using other stylesheets somewhere else?

Comment: How can I check for other StyleSheets ? Or better reset the StyleSheet before loading mine. I suspect I get the Lubuntu default qss/css. I am on Lubuntu Python 3.7.5 , PyQt5                              5.12.3

Comment: Mmmh. I thought I was using breeze, so I didn't test it out, but it seems that the breeze style (which is the default on Lubuntu) just ignores the background for focused items. Can you try other styles from Designer? Look for the "Preview in..." submenu in the "Form" menu.

Comment: Ok tried Designer preview in: windows behaves ok , button:pressed doesnt work but focus does ; fusion same as windows. Breeze color of button when focused is not the one I set up

Comment: As I thought. Breeze overrides some colors and behaviors if the css definition of the widget is not complete; what's strange is that you say button:pressed doesn't work, but it does in my tests. In any way, Fusion is the style that usually better handles stylesheets, if it's not a problem to use that, you can just set the application style by using `app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

musicmante qnswered my question:

As I thought. Breeze overrides some colors and behaviors if the css definition of the widget is not complete; what's strange is that you say button:pressed doesn't work, but it does in my tests. In any way, Fusion is the style that usually better handles stylesheets, if it's not a problem to use that, you can just set the application style by using app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion')).